# Issue with pip install

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to install matplotlib with pip, but I get this error:

[image]

Is this an issue with my proxy server?

Comment: Yes, there are problems with your internet connection. Also, please post output to the question body.

Comment: Please paste the text of the error, not a link to an image of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Find the version of Python that you are using (Is it 2.7 or 3.5 or any other?)
[image]

**Step 2:** Click on this link and find 'Matplotlib'.

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip

Download the .whl according to the version of python you are using.Here, I have shown for version 2.7

[image]

**Step 3:** Copy the .whl and place it in the Python 2.7 folder (find the location where Python is installed and pointing to).

**Step 4:** Run the executable as follows:

[image]

Lastly, *check your internet connection* as well. Hope this helps!